# Image Is Not Getting Download complete

Tags: iphone, ios, image

In my application if am downloading images form server in JPG format. I am downloading images using NSURLConnection Synchronously. But some times half of the image does not get download. and it even does not throw error message.

How can fix this bug. Any guide will be helpful.

---

i changed the image to base64 on server and convert to image on device then this problem goes away.

Comment: Post relevant code and try downloading the same jpg from your browser

Comment: Alternatively, I'd say do an Asynchronous request and check the data coming in with provided `NSURLConnection` delegate methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many people use `NSURLConnection` incorrectly, and do not check for an early server disconnect.

If the server disconnects before sending you the number of bytes specified in `Content-Length`, this will not produce an error and you will have an incomplete download. I've seen the same problem you describe because of this problem.

In `connection:didReceiveResponse:` you need to remember the value of `[response expectedContentLength]` and in `connectionDidFinishLoading:` you need to check that you received this many bytes. If not, you can generate your own error and cause the download to fail. You also need to handle the case where the content length is unknown (`expectedContentLength` will return `NSURLResponseUnknownLength`).